# Scheduled MySQL optimization

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I am looking for a way to schedule a database table optimisation on all MySQL data.

Currently I can do it by using the `mysqlcheck -o --all-databases` command, and I thought about scheduling it with cron, but the problem is that the password would remain cleartext inside /etc/crontab.

There is a scheduling feature in MySQL, but I don't know how it could fit the need, it sends MySQL commands, it doesn't launch shell programs.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use cron, use the --defaults-extra-file option to specify a file, in my.cnf format. It can contain the username/password needed.

Use standard linux permissions to make it only readable to the user running the cron task.

See third bullet-point here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't there a way to input the password hashed? Some programs allow that.

Comment: Bad news. I tried it, but mysqlcheck does not support the --defaults-file option. Pity.

Comment: It wouldn't be any more secure. If someone found the hashed password, they would be able to use it just like you.

Comment: It does on my 5.0.92 system - I use it :) Might just be a permissions issue.

Comment: The man page does not show it. And the hashed password is for obscurity mainly, but maybe you're right, this is nonsense.

Comment: Its not listed on the man page, as its not specific to mysqlcheck. It works for all the mysql client programs. It is listed on `mysqlcheck --help`

Comment: Works, it was a typo. Thanks